# counting records where criteria is met

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to count the records where a column field contains a certain string.

This is my query:

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("count(e.$column)")
        ->from("AppBundle:$table", "e")
        ->where("e.urlid LIKE \"-test\"")
        ->getQuery();
    $occurences = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```

It works when I run the manual query on mysql, so it's probably a doctrine thing. I'm getting this error from doctrine:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 66: Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '"'

Any help would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to correct set the like expression with someting like this:

```
$qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('user.name', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$name.'%')));
```

in your case try this:

```
 $key = '-test';
 $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
 $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $query = $qb
        ->select("count(e.$column)")
        ->from("AppBundle:$table", "e");

 $qb->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('e.urlid', $qb->expr()->literal('%'.$key.'%')));


$occurences = $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I have eventually managed to fix it lke this:

```
$query = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select("count(e.$column)")
        ->from("AppBundle:$table", "e")
        ->where("e.$column LIKE :url")
        ->setParameter("url", $url."%")
        ->getQuery();
$occurences = $query->getSingleScalarResult();
```